# Formula stored as text in Pandas DataFrame column, I need to evaluate it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a formula stored as text in a DataFrame, I tried to loop through the row using iteritems, it worked on a small dataset, but it took forever to run on 1 Million Records. 
I have tried the following, but it keeps throwing a syntax error.

Can anyone suggest a solution or a better way?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['1+1',''],['2+2',''],['x+3','3'],['x+5','7']])
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['F','W'])
df['F'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['F'].replace('x',x['W']),axis=1)
df['New']=df.eval(str(df['F']))
print (df)
```

Edit : 
and Below is the error traceback :

```
 File "C:\Users\lalkailani\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 367, in visit
    node = ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.parse(clean))

  File "C:\Users\lalkailani\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    0 1 +1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you share the error traceback

Comment: Don't call `str()`. Just do: `df['New']=df.eval(df['F'])`.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik removing the str() did solve it for the example I provided, but my original column includes different data types ( integer and strings ), I should have included that in the example.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik : After trying again, looks like it would work with different data types. Thanks, I will try it on the original data and hopefully, this will solve it.

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: now it gave me different Error I guess related to the data size 
AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'

I tried df['New']=df['F'].apply(literal_eval) , it gave me another Error : 
malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x000001DC6F2F9E48>